# Setting expiry date for Non-Renewable subscription using storekit

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase, non-renewing-subscription

I am writing a non-renewable subscription module for my new application. It includes 1 month, 3 month and 6 month subscription period. I do not understand, how to set expiry date using icloud. Any help would be appreciated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For **Apple**, there is no "within the validity period" for non-renewing subscriptions. The duration of the period, fortunately or unfortunately, is left up to the developer.

Subscription `validity/expiry date` is up to the developer.

It seems common for developers to use their own server to track the expiry period of a non-renewing subscription.

**"So if When you use iCloud for restoration you should have to manage expiry date on your own server...**"

> Non-renewable subscriptions. Subscriptions that don’t involve
>   delivering episodic content. Examples include access to a database of
>   historic photos or a collection of flight maps. It’s your app’s
>   responsibility to make the subscription available on all of the user’s
>   devices and to let users restore the purchase. This product type is
>   often used when your users already have an account on your server that
>   you can use to identify them when restoring content. Expiration and
>   the duration of the subscription are also left to your app (or your
>   server) to implement and enforce.
>
> https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Products.html

Hope it help you.

Comment: But if I store expiration date on device then if user changes device then new there is no way to keep track. To store expiration date on iCloud, I need to store some document file, where I will save expiration dates for subscriptions. I think, it is also not suitable method. I think, I will go for Firebase.

Comment: you can save expiration date on your server (backend) it can be anything firebase or any other server which you use to consume web API.

Comment: something like you can use iCloud for non-renewable subscription and you need to use Backend server for save expiry date... I highlight sentence in my answer. in short For Apple, there is no "within the validity period" for non-renewing subscriptions. The duration of the period, fortunately or unfortunately, is left up to the developer.